# default value for collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection

Tags: ios, swift

What value do I have to return from `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForFooterInSection` if I want everything to work like before.

**Background:** I want to disable the footer for some sections, so I am returning `CGSize.zero` for those, but I don't know what to return for the ones that should be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From function's documentation

> If you do not implement this method, the flow layout uses the value in
>   its  footerReferenceSize property to set the size of the footer.

So simply return `footerReferenceSize` from you flow layout, like so

```
if let collectionViewFlowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    return collectionViewFlowLayout.footerReferenceSize

}
```

Comment: the function has collectionViewLayout as parameter, so you can directly do `collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: Yes, I forgot that this function receives the layout as parameter